# What is the HTML character reference code for the percent sign (%)?

Tags: html, character

I want to use the code associated to the character `%`. For example when we want to write `é` then we code `&eacute;` , so what is the code for `%` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are many possibilities:

```html
&percnt;
&#x00025;
&#37;
```

A reference with all possible characters you find on the following site: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: is the code `&percnt;` supported in HTML4 and earlier ?

Comment: Yes but not on "HTML 4.01 Frameset" - tested with jsfiddle.net

Comment: so it is better to use `&#37;` then :)

Comment: I dont want to use something HTML4 or earlier but I want to be careful if end-user's browser doesn't support some codes :)

Comment: I think every modern browser should do the job.

Comment: every modern browser... ;)

Answer (score 6):

For percent sign the HTML equivalent is:

```html
&#37;
```

---

You can find the HTML codes for Unicode symbols [here](http://unicode-table.com/ru/#03CA).